draggablescrollablesheet in flutterwith singlechildscrollview
I am trying to implement DraggableScrollableSheet in Flutter below the singlechildscrollview. But I want to place the DraggableScrollableSheet exactly at the bottom of the singlechildscrollview when it reaches the bottom then it should show up and scroll with the handle please see the gif image for reference

Below is my code
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Where are you going today?'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Hi, Vidhan!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Your location',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Map Placeholder'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 200), // Placeholder to show more content
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.3,
            minChildSize: 0.1,
            maxChildSize: 0.7,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      width: 40,
                      height: 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Where to?'),
                            trailing: Text('Manage'),
                          ),
                          GridView.count(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                            children: [
                              LocationCard(title: 'Home', location: 'Mathura, India'),
                              LocationCard(title: 'Office', location: 'Mumbai, India'),
                              LocationCard(title: 'Salon', location: 'Mathura, India'),
                              LocationCard(title: 'Friend\'s Home', location: 'Agra, India'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Your code is working well my side and only bottom sheet is scrolled not whole UI

yes that is the problem

Check your whole code and scrolling physics
